# Google Plus Signin 'Unknown RPC service: widget-interactive-I0_1370237493291'

Tags: google-plus

Sorry for such a noob question.

I just followed following google plus signin's Step1 to Step4.
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/
The signin seemed to succeed, while an error 'Unknown RPC service: widget-interactive-I0_1370237493291' emerged. Here are the console logs on Chrome.

```
XHR finished loading: "https://plusone.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.connect.en_US.B31L_d…sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=GA/rs=AItRSTOhxGvE7YZFbwjOy6nLkxCnNjz3og/cb=gapi.loaded_1". signin:15
XHR finished loading: "https://plusone.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.hgKKOofQjvI.…sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=EQ/rs=AItRSTOeNwU4i5ApX9gPGjnZ0AzovKWmWw/cb=gapi.loaded_0". signin:15
Unknown RPC service: widget-interactive-I0_1370237493291 cb=gapi.loaded_0:71
signed in
```

I think the error is about something incomplete. I cannot figure out what the exactly the error is and how to get it clear. What am I missing?

Here is the code. The origin is `http://localhost:3000`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Gplus</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Gplus</h1>
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="362449793624.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
  </span>
</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function signinCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['access_token']) {
    // Successfully authorized
    // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
    document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    console.log('signed in');
  } else if (authResult['error']) {
    // There was an error.
    // Possible error codes:
    //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
    //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
    // console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}
      </script>
     <!-- Place this asynchronous JavaScript just before your </body> tag -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
       var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
       po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem when I was trying that code sample. When trying to figure it out, I found this post:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-plus-developers/Ax3cMLhMR4Q

in the Google+ Developers Forum that seems to indicate that it's not really an 'error' but some kind of warning. If I find out more, I'll post an update here.

Hope this helps.